# Union-within-structure syntax in ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

Quick question about ctypes syntax, as documentation for Unions isn't clear for a beginner like me.

Say I want to implement an INPUT structure (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646270(v=VS.85).aspx)):

```
typedef struct tagINPUT {
  DWORD type;
  union {
    MOUSEINPUT    mi;
    KEYBDINPUT    ki;
    HARDWAREINPUT hi;
  } ;
} INPUT, *PINPUT;
```

Should I or do I need to change the following code?

```
class INPUTTYPE(Union):
    _fields_ = [("mi", MOUSEINPUT),
                ("ki", KEYBDINPUT),
                ("hi", HARDWAREINPUT)]

class INPUT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("type", DWORD),
                (INPUTTYPE)]
```

Not sure I can have an unnamed field for the union, but adding a name that isn't defined in the Win32API seems dangerous.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your Structure syntax isn't valid:

```
AttributeError: '_fields_' must be a sequence of pairs
```

I believe you want to use the [anonymous](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Structure._anonymous_) attribute in your ctypes.Structure.  It looks like the ctypes documentation creates a [TYPEDESC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221162.aspx) structure (which is very similar in construction to the tagINPUT).

Also note that you'll have to define DWORD as a base type for your platform.